# Calculate number of people over average

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I am trying to calculate how many people have a grade higher than average.
What I have currently instead returns the number of students and when I delete "=" from ">=" it returns 0.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM data.students
WHERE grade IN (SELECT grade 
               FROM data.students
               GROUP BY grade HAVING grade >= AVG(grade));
```

If I put an integer instead of `avg()` function I get good results.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the avg in a subquery is probably fastest:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   data.students
WHERE  grade > (SELECT avg(grade) FROM data.students);
```

`>` instead of `>=`, since you said *"a grade higher than average"*.

> What am I doing wrong?

In your subquery, `GROUP BY grade` aggregates to one row per distinct value of `grade`. `avg(grade)` is bound to be exactly the same as `grade` for every row (except `grade IS NULL`). Explains what you saw.
Your query was needlessly complex to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
       SELECT grade >= AVG(grade) OVER () AS tst
       FROM data.students
     ) AS a
WHERE a.tst= True
```